# No more data AJAX

Tags: html, ajax

So currently I'm searching for 10 new posts from the page and use `$_GET['limits']` in my PHP query.

So what I'd like to do is if there is no new data to show the 'No More Posts' Div. I tried an on error alert function with no luck.

```
var streams_stream_count=10;    
function streams_stream_load(targetID){
    $('#loadmorestreamoneajaxloadertarget').show();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url : 'stream2.php?limits='+streams_stream_count+'&targetID='+targetID,
        dataType : 'text',
        success: function (t) { 
            $('#streams_stream_container').fadeIn('slow').html(t); 
            $(document).scroll(function(){
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                    streams_stream_count+=10;streams_stream_load(targetID);
                }
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loadmorestreamoneajaxloadertarget').hide();
      }
  });
}
```

And my hidden div to show if no new data.

```
<div id='nomoreposts' style='display:none;'>No more Posts</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it in your `success` callback as you're not getting an error, you're just getting no data.  So, if `t` here is an array, you could just do something like: `if ( t.length === 0 ) { // show no more posts }`

Hope this helps.  Best.

Richard

Comment: Hi Richard, sounds like a great suggestions, only I have tried putting it in my success just before the page scroll doing if no data show div else show scroll more data. Doesn't seem to work .

Thank you

Comment: What did happen when you did that?  And did you put that in an `if` `else` block?

Comment: It just kept loading and searching for more data. And yes I did. I just don't know if it was in the right place.

Comment: Can you add that code that you tried in the `success` function that failed?